# How can support "Industrial 2 of 5 barcode" in Zxing project barcode scanner? -Android

Tags: java, android, zxing

In my Android app. I want to support barcode scanner for items. However, I used the Zxing project that provides a standalone barcode reader application which (via Android's intent mechanism ) can be called by other applications who wish to integrate barcode scanning.

Everything goes great, I scan barcode then check if any item from database exist or not to display it with its Info. Unluckily, when I attempt to scan **Industrial 2 of 5 barcode** (which a special type of barcodes) it is not work with me! it seems Zxing project does not support it!

The codes for Zxing project are: 
**IntentIntegrator class:**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2009 ZXing authors
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

 package com.google.zxing.integration.android;

 import java.util.Arrays;
 import java.util.Collection;
 import java.util.Collections;
 import java.util.HashMap;
 import java.util.List;
 import java.util.Map;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.AlertDialog;
 import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
 import android.content.DialogInterface;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
 import android.content.pm.ResolveInfo;
 import android.net.Uri;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;

/**
 * <p>A utility class which helps ease integration with Barcode Scanner via {@link     Intent}s. This is a simple
 * way to invoke barcode scanning and receive the result, without any need to integrate, modify, or learn the
 * project's source code.</p>
 *
 * <h2>Initiating a barcode scan</h2>
 *
 * <p>To integrate, create an instance of {@code IntentIntegrator} and call {@link #initiateScan()} and wait
 * for the result in your app.</p>
 *
 * <p>It does require that the Barcode Scanner (or work-alike) application is installed. The
 * {@link #initiateScan()} method will prompt the user to download the application, if needed.</p>
 *
 * <p>There are a few steps to using this integration. First, your {@link Activity} must implement
 * the method {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} and include a line of code like this:</p>
 *
 * <pre>{@code
 * public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
 *   IntentResult scanResult = IntentIntegrator.parseActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
 *   if (scanResult != null) {
 *     // handle scan result
 *   }
 *   // else continue with any other code you need in the method
 *   ...
 * }
 * }</pre>
 *
 * <p>This is where you will handle a scan result.</p>
 *
 * <p>Second, just call this in response to a user action somewhere to begin the scan process:</p>
 *
 * <pre>{@code
 * IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(yourActivity);
 * integrator.initiateScan();
 * }</pre>
 *
 * <p>Note that {@link #initiateScan()} returns an {@link AlertDialog} which is non-null if the
 * user was prompted to download the application. This lets the calling app potentially manage the dialog.
 * In particular, ideally, the app dismisses the dialog if it's still active in its {@link Activity#onPause()}
 * method.</p>
 *
 * <p>You can use {@link #setTitle(String)} to customize the title of this download prompt dialog (or, use
 * {@link #setTitleByID(int)} to set the title by string resource ID.) Likewise, the prompt message, and
 * yes/no button labels can be changed.</p>
 *
 * <p>Finally, you can use {@link #addExtra(String, Object)} to add more parameters to the Intent used
 * to invoke the scanner. This can be used to set additional options not directly exposed by this
 * simplified API.</p>
 *
 * <p>By default, this will only allow applications that are known to respond to this intent correctly
 * do so. The apps that are allowed to response can be set with {@link #setTargetApplications(List)}.
 * For example, set to {@link #TARGET_BARCODE_SCANNER_ONLY} to only target the Barcode Scanner app itself.</p>
 *
 * <h2>Sharing text via barcode</h2>
 *
 * <p>To share text, encoded as a QR Code on-screen, similarly, see {@link #shareText(CharSequence)}.</p>
 *
 * <p>Some code, particularly download integration, was contributed from the Anobiit application.</p>
 *
 * <h2>Enabling experimental barcode formats</h2>
 *
 * <p>Some formats are not enabled by default even when scanning with {@link #ALL_CODE_TYPES}, such as
 * PDF417. Use {@link #initiateScan(java.util.Collection)} with
 * a collection containing the names of formats to scan for explicitly, like "PDF_417", to use such
 * formats.</p>
 *
 * @author Sean Owen
 * @author Fred Lin
 * @author Isaac Potoczny-Jones
 * @author Brad Drehmer
 * @author gcstang
 */
public class IntentIntegrator {

      public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0x0000c0de; // Only use bottom 16 bits
      private static final String TAG = IntentIntegrator.class.getSimpleName();

      public static final String DEFAULT_TITLE = "Install Barcode Scanner?";
      public static final String DEFAULT_MESSAGE =
          "This application requires Barcode Scanner. Would you like to install it?";
      public static final String DEFAULT_YES = "Yes";
      public static final String DEFAULT_NO = "No";

      private static final String BS_PACKAGE = "com.google.zxing.client.android";
      private static final String BSPLUS_PACKAGE = "com.srowen.bs.android";

      // supported barcode formats
      public static final Collection<String> PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES = list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "RSS_14");
      public static final Collection<String> ONE_D_CODE_TYPES =
          list("UPC_A", "UPC_E", "EAN_8", "EAN_13", "CODE_39", "CODE_93", "CODE_128",
               "ITF", "RSS_14", "RSS_EXPANDED");
      public static final Collection<String> QR_CODE_TYPES = Collections.singleton("QR_CODE");
      public static final Collection<String> DATA_MATRIX_TYPES = Collections.singleton("DATA_MATRIX");

      public static final Collection<String> ALL_CODE_TYPES = null;

      public static final List<String> TARGET_BARCODE_SCANNER_ONLY = Collections.singletonList(BS_PACKAGE);
      public static final List<String> TARGET_ALL_KNOWN = list(
              BS_PACKAGE, // Barcode Scanner
              BSPLUS_PACKAGE, // Barcode Scanner+
              BSPLUS_PACKAGE + ".simple" // Barcode Scanner+ Simple
              // What else supports this intent?
          );

      private final Activity activity;
      private String title;
      private String message;
      private String buttonYes;
      private String buttonNo;
      private List<String> targetApplications;
      private final Map<String,Object> moreExtras;

      public IntentIntegrator(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
        title = DEFAULT_TITLE;
        message = DEFAULT_MESSAGE;
        buttonYes = DEFAULT_YES;
        buttonNo = DEFAULT_NO;
        targetApplications = TARGET_ALL_KNOWN;
        moreExtras = new HashMap<String,Object>(3);
      }

      public String getTitle() {
        return title;
      }

      public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
      }

      public void setTitleByID(int titleID) {
        title = activity.getString(titleID);
      }

      public String getMessage() {
        return message;
      }

      public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
      }

      public void setMessageByID(int messageID) {
        message = activity.getString(messageID);
      }

      public String getButtonYes() {
        return buttonYes;
      }

      public void setButtonYes(String buttonYes) {
        this.buttonYes = buttonYes;
      }

      public void setButtonYesByID(int buttonYesID) {
        buttonYes = activity.getString(buttonYesID);
      }

      public String getButtonNo() {
        return buttonNo;
      }

      public void setButtonNo(String buttonNo) {
        this.buttonNo = buttonNo;
      }

      public void setButtonNoByID(int buttonNoID) {
        buttonNo = activity.getString(buttonNoID);
      }

      public Collection<String> getTargetApplications() {
        return targetApplications;
      }

      public final void setTargetApplications(List<String> targetApplications) {
        if (targetApplications.isEmpty()) {
          throw new IllegalArgumentException("No target applications");
        }
        this.targetApplications = targetApplications;
      }

      public void setSingleTargetApplication(String targetApplication) {
        this.targetApplications = Collections.singletonList(targetApplication);
      }

      public Map<String,?> getMoreExtras() {
        return moreExtras;
      }

      public final void addExtra(String key, Object value) {
        moreExtras.put(key, value);
      }

      /**
       * Initiates a scan for all known barcode types.
       */
      public final AlertDialog initiateScan() {
        return initiateScan(ALL_CODE_TYPES);
      }

      /**
       * Initiates a scan only for a certain set of barcode types, given as strings corresponding
       * to their names in ZXing's {@code BarcodeFormat} class like "UPC_A". You can supply constants
       * like {@link #PRODUCT_CODE_TYPES} for example.
       *
       * @return the {@link AlertDialog} that was shown to the user prompting them to download the app
       *   if a prompt was needed, or null otherwise
       */
      public final AlertDialog initiateScan(Collection<String> desiredBarcodeFormats) {
        Intent intentScan = new Intent(BS_PACKAGE + ".SCAN");
        intentScan.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);

        // check which types of codes to scan for
        if (desiredBarcodeFormats != null) {
          // set the desired barcode types
          StringBuilder joinedByComma = new StringBuilder();
          for (String format : desiredBarcodeFormats) {
            if (joinedByComma.length() > 0) {
              joinedByComma.append(',');
            }
            joinedByComma.append(format);
          }
          intentScan.putExtra("SCAN_FORMATS", joinedByComma.toString());
        }

        String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intentScan);
        if (targetAppPackage == null) {
          return showDownloadDialog();
        }
        intentScan.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
        intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intentScan.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        attachMoreExtras(intentScan);
        startActivityForResult(intentScan, REQUEST_CODE);
        return null;
      }

      /**
       * Start an activity.<br>
       * This method is defined to allow different methods of activity starting for
       * newer versions of Android and for compatibility library.
       *
       * @param intent Intent to start.
       * @param code Request code for the activity
       * @see android.app.Activity#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
       * @see android.app.Fragment#startActivityForResult(Intent, int)
       */
      protected void startActivityForResult(Intent intent, int code) {
        activity.startActivityForResult(intent, code);
      }

      private String findTargetAppPackage(Intent intent) {
        PackageManager pm = activity.getPackageManager();
        List<ResolveInfo> availableApps = pm.queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
        if (availableApps != null) {
          for (ResolveInfo availableApp : availableApps) {
            String packageName = availableApp.activityInfo.packageName;
            if (targetApplications.contains(packageName)) {
              return packageName;
            }
          }
        }
        return null;
      }

      private AlertDialog showDownloadDialog() {
        AlertDialog.Builder downloadDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
        downloadDialog.setTitle(title);
        downloadDialog.setMessage(message);
        downloadDialog.setPositiveButton(buttonYes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            String packageName = targetApplications.get(0);
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + packageName);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            try {
              activity.startActivity(intent);
            } catch (ActivityNotFoundException anfe) {
              // Hmm, market is not installed
              Log.w(TAG, "Google Play is not installed; cannot install " + packageName);
            }
          }
        });
        downloadDialog.setNegativeButton(buttonNo, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {}
        });
        return downloadDialog.show();
      }


      /**
       * <p>Call this from your {@link Activity}'s
       * {@link Activity#onActivityResult(int, int, Intent)} method.</p>
       *
       * @return null if the event handled here was not related to this class, or
       *  else an {@link IntentResult} containing the result of the scan. If the user cancelled scanning,
       *  the fields will be null.
       */
      public static IntentResult parseActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
          if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            String contents = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT");
            String formatName = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_FORMAT");
            byte[] rawBytes = intent.getByteArrayExtra("SCAN_RESULT_BYTES");
            int intentOrientation = intent.getIntExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ORIENTATION", Integer.MIN_VALUE);
            Integer orientation = intentOrientation == Integer.MIN_VALUE ? null : intentOrientation;
            String errorCorrectionLevel = intent.getStringExtra("SCAN_RESULT_ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL");
            return new IntentResult(contents,
                                    formatName,
                                    rawBytes,
                                    orientation,
                                    errorCorrectionLevel);
          }
          return new IntentResult();
        }
        return null;
      }


      /**
       * Defaults to type "TEXT_TYPE".
       * @see #shareText(CharSequence, CharSequence)
       */
      public final AlertDialog shareText(CharSequence text) {
        return shareText(text, "TEXT_TYPE");
      }

      /**
       * Shares the given text by encoding it as a barcode, such that another user can
       * scan the text off the screen of the device.
       *
       * @param text the text string to encode as a barcode
       * @param type type of data to encode. See {@code com.google.zxing.client.android.Contents.Type} constants.
       * @return the {@link AlertDialog} that was shown to the user prompting them to download the app
       *   if a prompt was needed, or null otherwise
       */
      public final AlertDialog shareText(CharSequence text, CharSequence type) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        intent.setAction(BS_PACKAGE + ".ENCODE");
        intent.putExtra("ENCODE_TYPE", type);
        intent.putExtra("ENCODE_DATA", text);
        String targetAppPackage = findTargetAppPackage(intent);
        if (targetAppPackage == null) {
          return showDownloadDialog();
        }
        intent.setPackage(targetAppPackage);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_WHEN_TASK_RESET);
        attachMoreExtras(intent);
        activity.startActivity(intent);
        return null;
      }

      private static List<String> list(String... values) {
        return Collections.unmodifiableList(Arrays.asList(values));
      }

      private void attachMoreExtras(Intent intent) {
        for (Map.Entry<String,Object> entry : moreExtras.entrySet()) {
          String key = entry.getKey();
          Object value = entry.getValue();
          // Kind of hacky
          if (value instanceof Integer) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Integer) value);
          } else if (value instanceof Long) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Long) value);
          } else if (value instanceof Boolean) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Boolean) value);
          } else if (value instanceof Double) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Double) value);
          } else if (value instanceof Float) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Float) value);
          } else if (value instanceof Bundle) {
            intent.putExtra(key, (Bundle) value);
          } else {
            intent.putExtra(key, value.toString());
          }
        }
      }

    }
```

**IntentResult class:**

```
/*
 * Copyright 2009 ZXing authors
 *
 * Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
 * you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
 * You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *      http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */

package com.google.zxing.integration.android;

/**
 * <p>Encapsulates the result of a barcode scan invoked through {@link IntentIntegrator}.</p>
 *
 * @author Sean Owen
 */
public final class IntentResult {

  private final String contents;
  private final String formatName;
  private final byte[] rawBytes;
  private final Integer orientation;
  private final String errorCorrectionLevel;

  IntentResult() {
    this(null, null, null, null, null);
  }

  IntentResult(String contents,
               String formatName,
               byte[] rawBytes,
               Integer orientation,
               String errorCorrectionLevel) {
    this.contents = contents;
    this.formatName = formatName;
    this.rawBytes = rawBytes;
    this.orientation = orientation;
    this.errorCorrectionLevel = errorCorrectionLevel;
  }

  /**
   * @return raw content of barcode
   */
  public String getContents() {
    return contents;
  }

  /**
   * @return name of format, like "QR_CODE", "UPC_A". See {@code BarcodeFormat} for more format names.
   */
  public String getFormatName() {
    return formatName;
  }

  /**
   * @return raw bytes of the barcode content, if applicable, or null otherwise
   */
  public byte[] getRawBytes() {
    return rawBytes;
  }

  /**
   * @return rotation of the image, in degrees, which resulted in a successful scan. May be null.
   */
  public Integer getOrientation() {
    return orientation;
  }

  /**
   * @return name of the error correction level used in the barcode, if applicable
   */
  public String getErrorCorrectionLevel() {
    return errorCorrectionLevel;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString() {
    StringBuilder dialogText = new StringBuilder(100);
    dialogText.append("Format: ").append(formatName).append('\n');
    dialogText.append("Contents: ").append(contents).append('\n');
    int rawBytesLength = rawBytes == null ? 0 : rawBytes.length;
    dialogText.append("Raw bytes: (").append(rawBytesLength).append(" bytes)\n");
    dialogText.append("Orientation: ").append(orientation).append('\n');
    dialogText.append("EC level: ").append(errorCorrectionLevel).append('\n');
    return dialogText.toString();
  }

}
```

**To call Zxing in desired Activity:**

```
         //instantiate ZXing integration class
        IntentIntegrator scanIntegrator = new IntentIntegrator(this);
        //start scanning
        scanIntegrator.initiateScan();
```

**To get scanning result by:**

```
if (scanningResult != null) {
        //get content from Intent Result
        String scanContent = scanningResult.getContents();
        //get format name of data scanned
        String scanFormat = scanningResult.getFormatName();
 }
```

**Industrial 2 of 5 barcode example:**

[image]

I see some barcodes scanner support Industrial 2 of 5 barcode as Accusoft Barcode Scanner; but I used Zxing cause it is available for developer to include it in project!

I see like http://www.onbarcode.com/products/android_barcode/barcodes/code_2_of_5.html and others for Zxing project but I did not find any way can help me!

**In sum:** Is there any way to support Industrial 2 of 5 barcode in Zxing project? **or** may there is any  way to support it by another project rather than Zxing?

sorry for this long question! any suggestions or  help will be appreciated, thanks in advance !

Comment: I guess if ZXing doesn't support Industrial 2 of 5 barcode you can not use it for such barcodes. If you would like to support ZXing and implement this possibility you should probably start from their forum - https://groups.google.com/group/zxing

Comment: yes I noted that it does not support it! I will see the forum, thanks!

Comment: ITF (Interleaved 2 of 5) is supported, although, ITF actually names a lot of variations. That actually doesn't look like ITF, although it's hard to ever know for sure from a picture. Are you sure of the format?

Comment: I mean in my question Industrial 2 of 5 code, not Interval 2 of 5 code please.. however, as I see it does not support in zxing project barcode scanner; as when I attempt to scan it, it does not work with me! Mr. @Sean Owen.

Comment: It may just be that your barcode or image is bad. You should provide a link to the format and a pure sample.

Comment: yes sorry for that Mr. @Sean Owen, I update my post! actually, I scan the barcode which in image by Accusoft Barcode Scanner and the result like this: barcode:0021 ; Format: ITF ! which not support by Zxing project ...

Comment: thanks all. the problem processed as when the bar-code scanner can't deal with bar-code; the input dialog appear to user to enter the bar-code manually! i know it is not the best solution but it works well with me for now; furthermore there is a suggestion to change the type of bar-code form its generator such a type that the bar-code scanner can scan it by zxing project!  @Stan

Answer (score -1):

Zxing doesnt support this format ! Used our own app which uses zxing....

Comment: yes thanks I noticed that, it does not support this format, but please what do you mean by your app?! furthermore, I let the user to input the  bar-code manually in case 2 of 5 bar-code (it works well until now)! @Why-K-Rum

Comment: our app which uses zxing library. I tried scanning this barcode and it didnt. Thats what I meant there, glad that you found out an alternative. ATB !

Comment: you can up vote if I was any of your assistance. Thanks.