# Use Barcode Scanner embeded in frame android

Tags: android, camera, barcode, zxing, zbar

I want to create an app that scanned and get code from a qr-code barcodes.

In main layout I have a rectangle frame that show camera view [always app is open].

A textview is below of frame. 
[image]

When a qr-code put in frame code of barcode scanned and copied to textview.

How can I implement this idea?

How to customize barcode scanner library like [zxing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing/) for that?

How to capture picture and get code of inside that?

Comment: to use zxing you can see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21293801/how-can-support-industrial-2-of-5-barcode-in-zxing-project-barcode-scanner-a  or this http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android-sdk-create-a-barcode-reader--mobile-17162

Comment: thanks @MaheeraJazi-newaccount- but i decide to use the zxing library in a rectangular frame in my application and that frame is always showing and wait for qr-code. my problem is the way of  implementation that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would require modifications to the zxing library. There is a [third party project](https://github.com/mitoyarzun/zxingfragmentlib) that added fragment support to zxing, you should check it out.